# PS4 controller now connecting? Reset doesn't work

Tags: ps4, controllers

I was using my PS4 perfectly fine last night and then I turned it all off to go to sleep. I woke up this morning and when I press the ps button on my controllers they simply flash a blue light and then go off- sometimes they flash continuously, after holding down the ps button but they do not turn my PlayStation on. I have two controllers and they both do the exact same thing.
When I turn on the PlayStation on by the box, it tells me there has been a serious issue and it needs to restart but for that, I need to connect a controller and it doesn't work.
Everything online tells me to press the restart button on the back on the controller and then connect them via USB but it still isn't working!!!!
I am so confused, especially as it is the exact same with both my controllers and I was only using one last night.
Pleaseeeee help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a duplicate, because OP mentioned that "there has been a serious issue and (the PS4) needs to restart" - so I will provide a possible course of action here.

Do not try this before you tried everything else described in similar questions and their respective answers!

### Playstation 4 Safe Mode

The PS4 has a safe mode, that allows you to access a stripped down version of the OS - doing anything in there may damage your data for good, so do not try this unless there is nothing else to try or you have a recent backup!

[Using safe mode](https://support.playstation.com/s/article/Safe-Mode-PS4?language=en_US):

1. Turn off PS4 (not standby)
2. Press and hold the power button, release it after the second beep (beeps should be 7s apart)
3. Connect a DS4 controller with USB cable and press the PS button

Try to restart the PS4 from here. If your controller still does not connect, even in safe mode, there might be a problem with your controller or with your USB cable.

Otherwise enter safe mode again try these options in this order (I will warn you again: **Do not try this unless you are very sure!**):

1. Restore Default Settings (resets all of your settings)
2. Rebuild Database (takes long, pretty much rewrites all of the data - may fail)
3. Initialize PS4 (this deletes all of your settings and data, except for the firmware - basically puts it into the state it was in, when it left its packaging)
4. Initialize PS4 (Reinstall System Software) (deletes absolutely everything, you will have to reinstall a firmware manually)